# Sending js array to php results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

Alright, so I'm looking for a way to get a jQuery autocomplete code to pass through a form and show results with php, so that I can for example add timezones to the countries (See code below). I haven't been successful as I'm fairly new and I would love to get some help.

This is the countries js array I need php to show results for (Each timezone for each country):

```
var countries = {
  "AD": "Andorra",
  "AE": "United Arab Emirates",
  "AF": "Afghanistan",
  "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
  "AI": "Anguilla",
  "AL": "Albania",
  "AM": "Armenia",
  "AN": "Netherlands Antilles",
  "AO": "Angola",
  "AQ": "Antarctica",
  "AR": "Argentina",
  "AS": "American Samoa",
  "AT": "Austria",
  "AU": "Australia",
  "AW": "Aruba",
  "AX": "\u00c5land Islands",
  "AZ": "Azerbaijan",
  "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
  "BB": "Barbados",
  "BD": "Bangladesh",
  "BE": "Belgium",
  "BF": "Burkina Faso",
  "BG": "Bulgaria",
  //list goes on
}
```

[I got the code from here](http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) (If this helps with understanding what this is).

Comment: Why are you not just adding this array of countries to your PHP code?

Comment: Could you send me something on how to do that? I'm a really newbie with php and js even though I have some experience with CSS and HTML.

Thank you to the person who edited my post too!

Comment: Just do `$countries = array(
  "AD" => "Andorra",
  "AE" => "United Arab Emirates",
  "AF" => "Afghanistan",
  // list goes on
  );`

Comment: What about the autocomplete then? I really want to keep that...